# AWK FNR==NR on an Empty File

Tags: bash, awk

I am running the following command which works great as long as their is content in the first file:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[tolower($1)]++; next} !a[tolower($1)]' OutSideSyncUsers.csv NewUsers.csv
```

If the first file is empty, the command doesnt work. I found online this reference:

> all the programs that use the two-files idiom will not work correctly
>   if the first file is empty (in that case, awk will execute the actions
>   associated to NR==FNR while reading the second file). To correct that,
>   you can reinforce the NR==FNR condition by adding a test that checks
>   that also FILENAME equals ARGV[1].

Im not sure I understand how (or where) in the query  to add the test check equals ARGV[1]

Any help would be apperciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this additional conditions like this:

```
awk -F, 'ARGV[1] == FILENAME{a[tolower($1)]++; next} !a[tolower($1)]' OutSideSyncUsers.csv NewUsers.csv
```

Additional condition `ARGV[1]==FILENAME` ensures that first block only executes for the first file only in argument list. When first file is empty then it will just skip the first block. This way you make sure 2nd block `!a[tolower($1)]` is always executing on 2nd file in argument list.

Comment: awesome, your explanation is exactly the info I was looking for

Comment: I've added explanation in my answer. `FILENAME` is already set by `awk` to the current input filename.

Comment: so does this code still work if the second file is ever blank? or will that cause a problem?

Comment: If 2nd file is empty, do you want all lines to be printed from 1st file or not print anything at all?

Comment: To answer your question, yes this command works fine even if 2nd file is blank and it will just skip printing anything.

Comment: so if the first and second file is empty, i would just want it to create a blank file. because I only want the differences from the second file

Comment: Yes if both files are empty or just the 2nd file is empty then output will blank.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU awk use ARGIND:

```
awk -F, '{k=tolower($1)} ARGIND==1{a[k]; next} !(k in a)' OutSideSyncUsers.csv NewUsers.csv
```

with other awks an approximation is:

```
awk -F, '{k=tolower($1)} FILENAME==ARGV[1]{a[k]; next} !(k in a)' OutSideSyncUsers.csv NewUsers.csv
```

but that fails if/when you are parsing the same file twice so then you can set variables between the files:

```
awk -F, '{k=tolower($1)} !f{a[k]; next} !(k in a)' OutSideSyncUsers.csv f=1 NewUsers.csv
```