# Merge two files using AWK with conditions

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am new to bash scripting and need help with below Question. I parsed a log file to get below and now stuck on later part.
I have a file1.csv with content as:

```
mac-test-1,10.32.9.12,15
mac-test-2,10.32.9.13,10
mac-test-3,10.32.9.14,11
mac-test-4,10.32.9.15,13
```

and second file2.csv has below content:

```
mac-test-3,10.32.9.14
mac-test-4,10.32.9.15
```

I want to do a file comparison and if the line in second file matches any line in first file then change the content of file 1 as below:

```
mac-test-1,10.32.9.12, 15, no match
mac-test-2,10.32.9.13, 10, no match
mac-test-3,10.32.9.14, 11, matched
mac-test-4,10.32.9.15, 13, matched
```

I tried this

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a {print $0",""matched"}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

but it prints below and doesn't include the not matching records

```
mac-test-3,10.32.9.14,11,matched 
mac-test-4,10.32.9.15,13,matched
```

Also, **in some cases the file2 can be empty** so the result should be like this:

```
 mac-test-1,10.32.9.12,15, no match
 mac-test-2,10.32.9.13,10, no match
 mac-test-3,10.32.9.14,11, no match
 mac-test-4,10.32.9.15,13, no match
```

Comment: You should include in your example cases where the 1st field matches between the 2 files but the 2nd field doesn't (and vice-versa) so we can see how you want those handled. Right now we can't tell if you want to match on the first field or the second or both and your statement `if the line in second file matches any line in first file` doesn't reflect your expected output since there are no cases where the whole line from file1 matches the whole line from file2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not printing the else case:

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}
{
 if ($1 in a) {
  print $0 ",matched"
 } else {
  print $0 ",no match"
 }
}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Output

```
mac-test-1,10.32.9.12,15,no match
mac-test-2,10.32.9.13,10,no match
mac-test-3,10.32.9.14,11,matched
mac-test-4,10.32.9.15,13,matched
```

Or in short, without manually printing the comma but using OFS:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{ print $0 OFS (($1 in a)?"":"no")"match"}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

**Edit**

I found a solution on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012556/awk-fnr-nr-on-an-empty-file) handling FNR==NR on an empty file.

When file2.csv is empty, all output lines will be:

```
mac-test-1,10.32.9.12,15,no match
```

Example

```
awk -F "," '
ARGV[1] == FILENAME{a[$1];next}
{
 if ($1 in a) {
  print $0 ",matched"
 } else {
  print $0 ",no match"
 }
}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Comment: This is what I was looking on how to use if else condition with this. Only one issue with this solution how do I handle the case when the file 2 is empty/null then all the records in file 1 to be populated as no match?

Comment: @AkashDeep That is how the mechanism works, you first create an array with all the entries from `file2.csv` and then when processing the second file there is a print for the if and the else.

Comment: @AkashDeep, What do you want to do with empty lines?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have a use case where in some scenario file 2 can be empty so in that case all the records of file 1 should be updated with "no match".

Comment: @AkashDeep I have added another example in case file2.csv is empty

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. You need not to check condition first and then print the statement because when you are checking `$1 in a` then those items who doesn't exist will NEVER come inside this condition's block. So its better to print whole line
of `file1.csv` and then print status of that particular line either its matched OR not-matched based on their existence inside array.

```
awk '
BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  print $0,(($1 OFS $2) in arr)?"Matched":"Not-matched"
}
' file2.csv file1.csv
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding a solution to handle empty file of file2.csv scenario here, same concept wise as above only thing it handles scenarios when file2.csv is an Empty file.

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < file2.csv) '
BEGIN  { FS=OFS=","}
(lines==0){
  print $0,"Not-Matched"
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
{
  print $0,(($1 OFS $2) in arr)?"Matched":"Not-matched"
}
' file2.csv file1.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, the above script prints nothing if the file2 is empty. I want to handle a scenario that when file 2 is empty then it should print like this:   mac-test-1,10.32.9.12,15, no match
 mac-test-2,10.32.9.13,10, no match
 mac-test-3,10.32.9.14,11, no match
 mac-test-4,10.32.9.15,13, no match

Comment: @AkashDeep, Sure let me check and get back here.

Comment: @AkashDeep, I have added **EDIT** solution now in my answer, kindly do check it once and let me know how it goes. When I tested it, it worked fine for me with an empty file2.csv scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this and post here if it works :)

Comment: @AkashDeep, Your welcome, try it out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @AkashDeep, Also Akash, you need to change file2's real name 2 places if you see code carefully in case your Real file's name is something different FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Each of @RavinderSingh13's and @Thefourthbird's answers contain large parts of the solution but here it is all together:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { key = $1 FS $2 }
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
        arr[key]
        next
    }
    {
        print $0, ( key in arr ? "matched" : "no match") 
    }
' file2.csv file1.csv
```

or if you prefer:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { key = $1 FS $2 }
    !f {
        arr[key]
        next
    }
    {
        print $0, ( key in arr ? "matched" : "no match") 
    }
' file2.csv f=1 file1.csv
```